# Do something in hook_node_load only when displaying node

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

Is there a way to run a specific block of instructions in hook_node_load only when the node is loaded do be displayed and not when it's loaded in the edit form?

The only way I can imagine is analyzing the url and if the pattern is node/%/edit don't execute the code.

I know I can also use hook_node_view, but in this case I have to add render arrays instead of simple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to examine the URL for this.

Loading a node is (correctly), completely de-coupled from displaying a node. `node_load()` doesn't know *what* you've loaded the node for; it doesn't care, its only responsibility is to prepare the node object.

So the context you're looking for doesn't conceptually exist when `hook_node_load()` is invoked, as that by definition has to happen before the object is passed to `node_view()`, and there's no way to signal your desired intent to `node_load()`

Comment: I can't use menu_get_object() because it seems to call node_load() somewhere and go recursively. But your answer is ok for me.

Comment: Oh yeah, dumb moment, sorry about that